# TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, parent task is not waiting for child completion

Tags: c#, task

Consider the following snippet

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parent starting..");
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                Task.Factory.StartNew(obj =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\tChild #{obj} starting...");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine($"\tChild #{obj} done..");
                }, i, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
            Console.WriteLine("Parent done..");
        });

task.Wait();
```

Which outputs

```
Parent starting..
Parent done..
        Child #0 starting...
        Child #2 starting...
        Child #9 starting...
        Child #5 starting...
        Child #1 starting...
        Child #6 starting...
        Child #4 starting...
        Child #3 starting...
        Child #7 starting...
        Child #0 done..
        Child #1 done..
        Child #8 starting...
        Child #6 done..
        Child #3 done..
        Child #5 done..
        Child #4 done..
        Child #9 done..
        Child #2 done..
        Child #7 done..
        Child #8 done..
```

How is this possible? The documentation clearly states that `StartNew` (on the parent) has the default creation options, which does not deny a child from attaching to it.

Why isn't `task.Wait()` on the parent blocking until the children complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you print `Parent done..` from *within* the parent task. The parent task, at this point, is still executing and attached children are irrelevant.

It's only when the code for the task *returns* control back to the TPL that it considers whether any children are attached and thus whether or not to mark the `Task` object as completed.

Attached children are *not* "arbitrarily block the parent task from executing until this task is complete". If they were, each iteration of that `for` loop, which is also running in the parent task, would be suspended and make creating the tasks in a loop pointless.

Comment: Ah this makes perfect sense. I do get your third point, I could have worded the question better perhaps, I assumed .wait() would block until the execution context of all the children signaled they were completed back to the parent.

Answer (score 2):

Your parents task is to make children. It does and finished. Children need to care for themself after it.

If you want your parent to wait for its children, you could do something like the following:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Parent starting..");
    var childTasks = new Task[10];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        childTasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(obj =>
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"\tChild #{obj} starting...");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            System.Console.WriteLine($"\tChild #{obj} done..");
        }, i, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
    }

    Task.WaitAll(childTasks);
});

task.Wait();
System.Console.WriteLine("Parent done..");
```

Comment: I know I can do that to "fix" my code, the question is why doesn't it do what (I understand) to be its documented and intended behavior, which is to create a dependency between parent and child, such that parent doesn't complete until all the children complete.

Comment: Got you wrong and fixed "Parent done..." output without mentioning it ... my bad! Glad you got your answer =)